# Delphi TStringList CustomSort on Name

Tags: delphi, sorting, tstringlist

I try to sort an TStringList on the Name part. For do that, I use the customSort method.

I show you a little example :

```
    function CompareString(List : TStringList; Index1, Index2 : integer) : integer;
    begin
        result := AnsiCompareText(List.Names[Index1], List.Names[Index2]);
    end;
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Memo2.Clear;
        Liste.CustomSort(CompareString);     
        Memo2.Lines.Append(Liste.GetText)
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Liste := TStringList.Create;
        Liste.Append('INFOS_NEGOCE=NUM_CDE');
        Liste.Append('INFOS_NEGOCE=DATE_CDE');
        Liste.Append('INFOS_NEGOCE=NOM_REPERTOIRE_ENT');
        Liste.Append('INFOS_NEGOCE=NOM_CONTACT');     
        Memo1.Lines.Clear;
        Memo1.Lines.Append(Liste.GetText)
    end;
```

The sort give me this result :

```
INFOS_NEGOCE=NOM_REPERTOIRE_ENT

INFOS_NEGOCE=NOM_CONTACT

INFOS_NEGOCE=NUM_CDE

INFOS_NEGOCE=DATE_CDE
```

I think that the sort DON'T change the order of the line (the name is always INFOF_NEGOCE).

Comment: What result did you expect? Also, you do know there is a `Sort` method on `TStringList`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The sorting is done with QuickSort. This means that the order of identical items (as seen by the sort) is undefined.

See [Quicksort - Repeated Elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements)

Comment: @mbratch, but the sort routine looks only for the name part and those are identical.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a quicksort. So I have not solution. I'll change of way for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
function CompareString(List : TStringList; Index1, Index2 : integer) : integer;
begin
  Result := AnsiCompareText(List.Names[Index1], List.Names[Index2]);
  // If you want to sort equal strings then on the Values
  if Result = 0 then Result := AnsiCompareText(List.ValueFromIndex[Index1], List.ValueFromIndex[Index2]);
  // Or if you want to keep the original order
  { if Result = 0 then Result := Index1-Index2; --- qv : this won't work!}
end;
```

`Result` would be set to `0` by your code if the `Names` were equal. If they are equal, choose which additional criteria you want to use to sort items with the same name.

---

As  Uwe Raabe correctly observes, the 'original order' won't work.

But all is not lost. Typically, the object included in a Tstringlist isn't used. If it's available, then just before the sort, try

```
for i := 0 to pred(List.Count) do List.Objects[i] := TObject(i);
```

and the sort becomes

```
function CompareString(List : TStringList; Index1, Index2 : integer) : integer;
begin
  Result := AnsiCompareText(List.Names[Index1], List.Names[Index2]);
  // If you want to sort equal strings then on the Values
  if Result = 0 then Result := AnsiCompareText(List.ValueFromIndex[Index1], List.ValueFromIndex[Index2]);
  // Or if you want to keep the original order
  if Result = 0 then Result := integer(List.Objects[Index1])-integer(List.Objects[Index2]);
end;
```

but it would be a lot easier if we were let in on the secret of what the "correct" order is expected to be.

Comment: It's better, but the result is not correct.

Comment: Index1 and Index2 don't represent the original order. They give the current order for the current sort iteration which is highly volatile.

Comment: @UweRaabe : this one should...